# Does Amazon SNS support token-based authentication with the Apple Push Notification Service?

Tags: apple-push-notifications, amazon-sns

I am looking to have a Push Notification service handling both FCM and Apple Push Notifications. I am looking into Amazon SNS but I can't figure out from the docs whether they support Token-Based authentication for Apple Push Notifications Service.

Answer (score 1):

Amazon SNS now supports APNS token-based authentication. https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2021/11/amazon-sns-token-authentication-api-mobile-notifications/

Answer (score 0):

Amazon SNS currently does not support token based APNS. Take a look on Firebase, it should be able to handle both.

Answer (score 0):

Amazon Pinpoint is capable of using `.p8` files when sending messages over APNS.